# what is the fastest way to retrieve comments (beautifulsoup or regular expression)

Tags: python

I have written this piece of code to retrieve comments from a webpage using BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
import bs4

with requests.session() as r:
    r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
    response = r.text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))

    for c in comments:
        print(c)
        print("==================================================")
```

Is this the best or fastest way to retrieve comments from the webpage or a regular expression would be faster?

Comment: You can try using the `time` module on both methods and checking which one does the job quicker. Just type `start_time` before the code and `end_time` after it and then do `end_time - start_time`. The output you'll get would be in seconds. Do it for both the methods you have in mind and decide which one is more efficient.

Comment: Time isn't the only consideration. Parsing is probably slower that regular expressions but probably more reliable.